# Cannot create zip archive

Tags: php, boolean-logic, php-ziparchive

I am trying to debug [this script](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php) to run on localhost. `$zip->status` returns `0`, which, according to [The Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php) means "no error", yet `file_exists()` still returns false.

I checked manually and the file does in fact not exist. I am running WAMP on localhost.

Why is this behaving this way? How can I fix it?

Here is my exact code:

```
$destination = "C:\wamp\www\temp\temp.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
echo var_dump($zip);
echo "<br />";
$zzz = $zip->open($destination, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($zzz === true) {
    echo "created archive<br />";
}else{
    //Var dump says it's true.. is that not a contradiction??
    echo var_dump($zzz)."<br />Couldn't create zipArchive<br />";
}
//add the files
foreach($_SESSION['images'] as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}

echo "Files ".$zip->numFiles."<br />Status ".$zip->status."<br />";

$zip->close();

if(!file_exists($destination)){
    echo "destination doesnt exist";        
}
```

And here is the output of that page..

```
object(ZipArchive)[1]
  public 'status' => int 0
  public 'statusSys' => int 0
  public 'numFiles' => int 0
  public 'filename' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'comment' => string '' (length=0)


created archive
Files 16
Status 0
destination doesnt exist
```

Comment: `echo var_dump();` is redundant.  You only need to use `var_dump();`  Additionally - when you iterate through your $_SESSION, consider adding `var_dump($file);` to output the names of the files to see if they are legitimate, readable files.  Presumably an empty zip file would not / might not get written, so I suspect the files being added may not be valid.

Comment: @cale_b I have this `if(false !== file_get_contents($fullimgpath,0,null,0,1)){ $_SESSION['images'][$n] = $fullimgpath; }` on another page verifying that the file do exist.

Comment: @cale_b Do the files have to be local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: After some discussion in chat we found out, that `$_SESSION['images']` contains `http://` urls but `ZipArchive` itself does not support adding files from remote sources. If you want to add remote images you'll have to download them before. So we've changed the `addFile()` related part to:

```
//add the files
foreach($images as $file) {
    $tmpname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'test');
    file_put_contents($tmpname, file_get_contents($file));
    $zip->addFile($tmpname, basename($file));
    unlink($tmpname);
}
```

---

Also there is is a logic error, or better, a typo. Replace

```
$zzz = $zip->open($destination, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($zzz !== true) {
    echo "created archive<br />";
} ...
```

by

```
$zzz = $zip->open($destination, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($zzz === true) {
    echo "created archive<br />";
} ...
```

---

Further note, that the zip is created in memory and will be written to disk not until calling [`ZipArchive::close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php). Check the first comment on the manual page:

> If you have created a zip file and added a file to it without error, yet the ZipArchive::close call fails (with ER_TMPOPEN: "Failure to create temporary file") and the zip file is not created, check to see if your ZipArchive::open call specifies a pathname containing nonexisting directories. If you expect a containing hierarchy of one or more directories, you must create them yourself before using using ZipArchive. You can write a simple function to recurse using dirname to find each parent directory, creating those that don't exist by using mkdir when leaving the recursion.

Comment: Ah.. woops, okay I edited my question. It's still not working.

Comment: what does `var_dump($zip->close());` say?

Comment: Thanks, but the directory itself exists. `C:\wamp\www\temp\` was copied directly from the location bar in windows explorer. Do the files themselves have to be local? Because they are not. Might that be the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28629/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-adelphia)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have `if($zzz !== true)` when it should be `if($zzz === true)`. xD